# In QnA maker bot I want to interrupt qnamaker dialogs

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am try to integrate my basic bot with "QnA-maker". After editing all the stuff i publish it to azure portal and try to check it and i am getting error.
The Error is when i open my bot to test it keeps the window waiting for my bot to ready.

Comment: 'Waiting for bot to be ready' is a pretty general error that is typically encountered when something in the code is preventing the bot from running. It's the same as 'Sorry, your bot is having an issue' when run locally. That said, did the bot run on Azure before you changed it to add QnA? And do you have a production endpoint in the bot file?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes it was running before my first editing, later i am getting issues. yes i have production endpoint in my bot file.

Comment: how did you set up your bot on azure?